# if statement in function working before the variables are even given a value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

I am working on a HTML, CSS,and Javascript document. I have created this:

```
let email = ''
let password = ''

function loginInfo() {
  email = document.getElementById('forma').value
  password = document.getElementById('forma').value
  setTimeout(5)
  if (password === '123') and (email==='email@gmail.com'); {
    console.log('succesful')
  }
}
setTimeout(5)
loginInfo()
```

When I run the program the `console.log('succesful')` runs no matter what, before I even type anything into the forms. Why wouldn't declaring the two variables at the top, `email` and `password` make it that the if statement if false and the code doesn't go through?

I tried adding the timeouts to delay this, and originally I thought all the problem was that I wasn't setting the variables as blank right away. It should be noted that when I first ran the program it did run any code in the if statement before I put data into the forms, but everytime after that it's continued to do it before. I even tried deleting the code, running, and putting it back but the problem still persists.

New:
HTML Code -

```
<form id="forma" action="">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="inputbox">
        <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
        <input type="email" required>
        <label for="">Email</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputbox">
        <ion-icon name="lock-closed-outline"></ion-icon>
        <input type="password" required>
        <label for="">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="forget">
        <label for=""><input type="checkbox" Remember Me <a href="#">Forget Password</a></label>

      </div>
      <button>Log in</button>
      <div class="register">
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register</a></p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Also, am I even referring to the password and email correctly too? Even though I think the problem will still happen.

Comment: `setTimeout(5)` does not do anything at all.

Comment: oh, ok -- but that was just added in and does not contribute to the problem

Comment: Well what's in the form? What are the initial values of the `<input>` fields?

Comment: You are using the same id for both the email and password, please use different ones

Comment: I've added the HTML form

Comment: `.getElementById('forma')` gets you the `<form>` element, not the `<input>` elements.

Comment: So how would I get that? Sorry, I'm kinda new at HTML and JS together, trying to learn.

Comment: @Pointy how would I go about getting that?

Comment: Well you could give them their own id values? Or classes?

Comment: @Pointy After assigning the ID like `<input type="password" id="passwordData" required>` and using it in JS like `password = document.getElementById('passwordData').value;` I still don't think the JS is seeing it... getElementById line still be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I see a few things straight away:

1. As mentioned, setTimeout does nothing here. It does not "slow down" the execution by that time, instead you call it as `setTimeout(whatToDo, afterHowLong)`, passing a function inside.

I assume what you're trying to do here is to check the form after some time. Ideally, you'd want to add a submit button to the form and check once that's clicked.

Alternatively, if there's really a reason the time has to be fixed, you'd need to rewrite the code by the correct timeout syntax, e.g.:

```js
function loginInfo() {
  email = document.getElementById('forma').value;
  password = document.getElementById('forma').value;
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (password === '123' && email==='email@gmail.com') {
      console.log('succesful')
    }
  }, 5);
}

loginInfo()
```

However, the immediate issue your code is encountering (i.e. why the log is running immediately), is of the malicious little semicolon after your if statement. E.g.:

```
if (condition); {
  code();
}
```

Here the if statement actually doesn't have a body, and instead the curlies serve as a scope that wraps the `code` inside, but is not in any way connected to the condition itself.

It's a nasty quirk of JS that I've had my fair share with.

That is of course disregarding the `and` (which doesn't work in JS, use `&&` instead), as well as the lack of parentheses around the whole condition expression.

Edit:

3. You want to access the individual input fields, as have been mentioned.

Assuming e.g.

```html
<body>
  <!-- ... -->
    <form id="forma">
      <input type="email" id="formEmailInput" />
      <input type="password" id="formPasswordInput" />
    </form>
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

You'd access values of those instead

```js
function loginInfo() {
  const email = document.getElementById('formEmailInput').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('formPasswordInput').value;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: To which the Boy Wonder exclaimed, "Holy Wandering Semicolons, " + Array(12).join("x"-1) + " Batman!";

Comment: Thanks, you did resolve my main problem. However, I've gotten this "Error: Cannot parse given Error objecthttps://4bdde533-446b-4c67-895c-ae53bdec2228.id.repl.co/__replco/static/devtools/devtools.js:57" now and not receiveing the console.log statement

Comment: @printAmerigo That would seem like a parse error in your repl.it. Perhaps the aforementioned `and`? Or possibly some other syntax error in your JS.

Comment: @J_H That is lovely! Though I prefer baNaNas for their elegance.

Comment: Hold on, I stopped recieving that. But now the code isn't even working... is it something with me getting the input data from the form as mentioned by @Pointy

Comment: @printAmerigo That's hard to say without seeing it as a whole. If you're asking about a small thing like this, it's generally best to share the repl.it in the question, that way anyone can quickly glance at it and see what's wrong.